# Customizing layout of gollum wiki

Tags: css, gollum-wiki

I would like to customize layout of a gollum wiki by:

1. moving sidebar to the left (it is on the right by default)
2. making the body of the page wider. Right now it takes slightly about a third of screen width and the text is really narrow.

I know that I am able to have a `custom.css` file in my repo that should load when I use the `--css` flag. However, I have no idea what to put in the file and looking at the css files in gollum repo has not proved helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I managed to figure out a way to get what I needed.

1. To place sidebar on the left add the following to `custom.css`:

```css
.has-rightbar #wiki-sidebar {
  float: left;
}

#wiki-body {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

2. To make the text wider:

```css
.has-sidebar #wiki-body {
  width: 77%;
}

#wiki-wrapper {
    max-width: 90%;
}

#wiki-sidebar {
  width: 17%;
}
```